# Jenkins declarative pipeline with list-git-branches-parameter-plugin

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline

I use listgitbranch plugin in my script but it doesn't work correctly and I faced with the following error.
This is the script:

```
- script:                                                                                                                                                           
    pipelineJob('app-Build-and-Deploy') {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
        parameters {                                                                                                                                                  
              listGitBranches(branchFilter: '(.*)/(.*)', defaultValue: 'master', name: 'BRANCH', type: 'BRANCH', remoteURL: 'git@git.mygit.com:app/my_app.git
        }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
        definition { ...
```

Error:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.BuildParametersContext.listGitBranches() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[branchFilter:(.*)/(.*), defaultValue:master, name:BRANCH, type:BRANCH, ...]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the right format:

```
          pipelineJob('app-Build-and-Deploy') {
              parameters {
                   listGitBranches{
                                   name('BRANCH')
                                   description('BRANCH')
                                   remoteURL('git@git.mygit.com:apps/my-app.git')
                                   credentialsId('deployer')
                                   defaultValue('master')
                                   branchFilter('(.*)/(.*)')
                                   type('BRANCH')
                                   sortMode('DESCENDING')
                                   selectedValue('TOP')
                                   tagFilter('')
                                   listSize('10')
                                   quickFilterEnabled(true)
                                }
                   }
```

Comment: Can it in local git repository?

Comment: yes, you just need to repo url.

Comment: mamnoon shiva
but I I think local git doesn't have any URL address!!!!

Comment: If your Jenkins is not on your local, yes you can't unless you have a public IP address.